# How do I make this website fit all screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm having trouble with screen sizes. I'm using Bootstrap for a lot of it.

Here are images: [image: wider screen size]

[image: my current size]

Sass source: `

```css
body
  background: $main-background
  margin: 0
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  
 .footer
  position: absolute
  color: white
  font-family: Arial
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  background-color: $plok-orange
  background-repeat: no-repeat
  background-size: 100%
  background-position: 50% 50%
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 1170px)
  min-width: 960px
  .footer
    width: 960px
    
.footer-left
  margin-top: $margin-top-footer
  float: left
  margin-left: 20px

.footer-left h1
  color: $plok-black
  font-size: 30px
  font-family: Helvetica
  font-weight: lighter

.footer-right
  margin-top: $margin-negative-footer
  float: right
  margin-left: 200px

.footer-right h1
  color: $plok-black
  font-size: 30px
  font-family: $font-stack
  font-weight: lighter
```

html source:

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">..........</h1>
        <p class="lead">........</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>..........</p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer-left">
            <h1>Preview</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img src="images/plokster-art-1.jpg" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img src="images/plokster-art-2.jpg" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img src="images/plokster-art-3.jpg" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="footer-right">
                    <h1>Contact</h1>
                </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I realize I'm not testing with the same max-width/min-width, but either way on my original screen size still does not fit. I'm using sass. `

Comment: Please post your html.

Comment: That `min-width: 960px` and `.footer { width: 960px}` for any resolution below 1170px doesn't look right, don't you want `@media screen and (min-width: 1170px)` instead? Try to identify one element a time and fix that element and then move to the next.

Comment: when using percentage based dimensions (such as width: 100%) you are doing 100% of parent. What you should look at here is your root class (jumbotron), which has no applied styling.

Comment: There is a `</form>` without having the opening tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need styling on your root element `jumbotron`

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. But here is my take.

Since your footer is `position: absolute` i would consider a relative parent. 
Try this on your root class

```
.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

maybe consider using the position absolute on the footer for its position

```
.footer {
  left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Remember that percentage based dimensions, such as `width: 100%` is based upon the parent element. 100% of parent is equal the dimension of the parent. Seems like you haven't styled your root element

Comment: styling jumptron with position: relative worked, thank you.